# h:selectBooleanCheckbox ajaxsupport event is not working if it exists in two different h:forms in jsf

Tags: jsf, richfaces, selectbooleancheckbox

Actually had `h:selectBooleanCheckbox` with `ajaxSupport` event inside one `<h:form id="form1">`, so while checking, invoking action/listener but once open modal panel and it contains `h:selectBooleanCheckbox` as well (which is inside another `<h:form id="form2">`), just close modal panel and try to check checkbox which is inside `form1`, but `ajaxSupport` and action is not invoking, please provide suggestion to fix.

The code is as follows:

```
<body>
<h:form id="form1">
        <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="customerActiveId"
                     value="#{manager.customerActive}">
                <a4j:support`enter code here`
                     action="#{bean[action]}"
                     event="onclick"
                     reRender="#{reRender}" />
        </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
        <br />
        <a4j:commandButton id="pnlConfigurationId"
                  value="project configuration"
                  oncomplete="$j('#pnlConfigurationMP').toggle();" />
        </h:form>    

        <rich:modalPanel id="pnlConfigurationMP" >
        <h:form id="form2" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="projectConfigurableId"
                     value="#{manager.projectConfigurable}">
                <a4j:support
                     action="#{bean[action]}"
                     event="onclick"
                     reRender="#{reRender}" />
        </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>

        <a4j:commandButton id="cancel" value="cancel" immediate="true" ajaxSingle="true"/>
        <a4j:commandButton id="save" value="save" action="#{manager.savePanel()}"/>

        </h:form>
        </rich:modalPanel>
      </body>
```

Actually ajax event and action is invoking on 'customerActiveId' check at firts time, but once open modal panel and simply close/cancel modal panel and try to check 'customerActiveId' again so ajax event and action is not invoking here

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]!

Comment: @JorgeCampos: I have added code snippet below

Comment: A `<body>` in a form???

Comment: @Kukeltje : Actually out side form, typo miss and modified